# vmstat + on RHEL machine high values of swpd

Tags: linux, hard-drive, memory, redhat-enterprise-linux, swap

The swpd field indicates how much swap space has been used; this value increases when your systems physical memory is full and the Linux kernel starts to use the swap partition/file. When the systems physical memory and swap space has been exhausted

from our RHEL 7.2 machine we can see the following

```
vmstat 1 20
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 3  0 1029076 6695152      4 49021608    1    1   520    32    2    2  9  1 90  0  0
 2  0 1029076 6694024      4 49022924    0    0 19612     0 5761 4269  7  1 91  0  0
 8  0 1029076 6665220      4 49021688    0    0 14812   707 22450 26191 13  3 84  0  0
 2  0 1029076 6656396      4 49021704    0    0 15748     0 17994 21252  9  2 88  0  0
 2  0 1029088 6649536      4 49022448    0   12 33972    12 13426 14773  8  2 90  1  0
 2  0 1029088 6687988      4 49022604    0    0 31212     0 6085 4391  7  2 91  0  0
 2  0 1029088 6688688      4 49022340    0    0 27040     9 7001 8469  4  1 95  1  0
 3  0 1029092 6689572      4 49022820    0    4 12136    28 3390 2773  4  0 96  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6689856      4 49022224    0    0 13776     0 3460 2841  4  0 96  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6690356      4 49021820    0    0 18444     0 3445 2819  4  0 96  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6689864      4 49021520    0    0 18768     0 3743 3005  4  0 96  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6693856      4 49021452    0    0 17544     0 3406 2732  4  0 96  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6694048      4 49021208    0    0 24244   292 4654 4816  4  1 95  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6695096      4 49021312    0    0 15572     0 3431 2835  4  0 96  0  0
 2  0 1029092 6694536      4 49022072    0    0 17476     0 5065 4033  7  1 91  0  0
 2  1 1029092 6685364      4 49022140    0    0 28112     9 24914 30798 10  3 86  1  0
 1  0 1029092 6684160      4 49021280    0    0 10356   104 14245 16378  5  2 93  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6671432      4 49022212    0    0 12816    20 11465 13620  5  1 94  0  0
 1  0 1029092 6707700      4 49022364    0    0 19840     0 4113 3603  4  0 95  0  0
 2  0 1029092 6706948      4 49022364    0    0 18128     0 3324 2833  4  0 96  0  0
```

dose high values of swpd indicate on problem?

```
 free -g
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            122          69           6           8          46          43
Swap:            15           0          14


vmstat 1 20
    128195440 K total memory
     72465912 K used memory
     77700088 K active memory
     36918416 K inactive memory
      6707164 K free memory
            4 K buffer memory
     49022360 K swap cache
     16351228 K total swap
      1029076 K used swap
     15322152 K free swap
    137196351 non-nice user cpu ticks
          778 nice user cpu ticks
     21836716 system cpu ticks
   1437416566 idle cpu ticks
      7095049 IO-wait cpu ticks
            0 IRQ cpu ticks
      1280657 softirq cpu ticks
            0 stolen cpu ticks
   8346063429 pages paged in
    515040249 pages paged out
      3267044 pages swapped in
      5005632 pages swapped out
   4242627451 interrupts
   1713287115 CPU context switches
   1705353038 boot time
     31037695 forks



sar -B 2 5 


03:37:14 PM  pgpgin/s pgpgout/s   fault/s  majflt/s  pgfree/s pgscank/s pgscand/s pgsteal/s    %vmeff
03:37:16 PM      0.00      6.00    133.50      0.00     93.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
03:37:18 PM      0.00      0.00     34.50      0.00     91.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
03:37:20 PM      0.00      4.50  50683.50      0.00  19022.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
03:37:22 PM     60.00      2.00  11028.50      0.00  10382.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
03:37:24 PM      0.00      0.00    805.00      0.00   1205.50      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
Average:        12.00      2.50  12537.00      0.00   6158.80      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00


sar -d 

03:34:42 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
03:34:52 PM       sda    448.60  20769.60     66.30     46.45      0.60      1.35      0.15      6.73
```